# SUPEE 7405/8788 Images won't upload

Tags: image-upload, supee-8788, supee-7405

I know that there are hundreds of questions about issues with SUPEE-8788 and I feel like i have been endlessly going through search results here and on Google to try and find a solution to this but here goes...

I recently installed SUPEE 7405 and 8788 on a Magento 1.9.1.0. I have cleared all the Magento caches, browser caches and reindexed but when I try to upload an image to a product it doesn't display in the admin.

Here's what happens:

1. Click Browse Files
2. Select image
3. Click Upload Files
4. Progress bar shows uploading and then completed

However, the image then doesn't display in the grid and it also hasn't uploaded. I believe that this is different to the permissions issue where the image does then show after upload but as a broken image due to file permissions.

Wondering if anyone can help?

Thanks.